# Run TelegramClient and enter the bot token but get an error

Tags: telegram

Running the code gives the following instructions

Please enter your phone (or bot token):

A phone number would work
However, if it is a bot token, I get an error
bot token is getting HTTP API from 'BotFather'

Isn't the bot token the HTTP API?

    What does the error below mean?

    telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.UserIsBotError:
    Bots can't send messages to other bots (caused by SendMessageRequest)

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl import functions, types

api_id     = xxxxxxxx
api_hash   = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
http_api   = 'abcdefghij:zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
bot_name   = 'anon'

client = TelegramClient(bot_name, api_id, api_hash)

async def main():    
    await client.send_message('me', 'Hello to myself!')
    
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: What is your question? You are confusing a client and bot.